# ffmpeg records RTSP only for 30 seconds and then freezes

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

while trying to record RTSP stream, I noticed that ffmpeg only records up to 30 seconds, and then it just simply freezes I pressure `Ctrl + C` to terminate.
I am running ffmpeg version 2.5.2

```
antony@medina:~$ ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.0.112:554/11 -vcodec copy ~/test.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.5.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 25 2014 00:04:42 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libpulse --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvo-aacenc
  libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
  libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
  libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
  libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
  libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://192.168.0.112:554/11':
  Metadata:
    title           : \11
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.039900, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 1280x720, 25.08 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/antony/test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    title           : \11
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 17 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_alaw (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 0x343c1e0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[NULL @ 0x31cf840] RTP: missed 8 packetskB time=00:00:02.59 bitrate=1084.8kbits/s    
^Cav_interleaved_write_frame(): Immediate exit requested.56 bitrate=1492.1kbits/s    
frame=  751 fps=9.5 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5415kB time=00:00:29.88 bitrate=1484.3kbits/s    
video:5449kB audio:64kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Received signal 2: terminating.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the following switch `-rtsp_transport tcp` is required

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.0.112:554/11 ~/Videos/stream.mkv
```

Comment: Where is the document to specify this? Thanks!

Comment: `-rtsp_transport tcp` may lead to steam stutters. Have you meet this problem?